# Returning largest dictionary sum from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

Given a list of dictionaries, how do I return the dictionary with the largest sum

```
>>>testing
[{'key1': 1, 'key2': 14, 'key3': 47},
 {'key1': 222, 'key2': 222, 'key3': 222},
  {'key1': 0, 'key2': 0, 'key3': 0}]
```

I'd want to return

```
{'key1': 222, 'key2': 222, 'key3': 222}
```

So far I've tried `[sum(i.itervalues()) for i in testing]` which would tell me which of the items in the list has the largest value, but I'm lost as to how to just return the list. I'm using Python 2.7 fwiw.

Comment: `max(testing, key=lambda x: sum(x.itervalues()))`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) with a parameterized `key`:

```
result = max(testing,key=lambda x : sum(x.itervalues()))
```

`max(..)` with a `key` returns the largest value of the given `iterable` according to the given `key` function.

Running this with `python` gives:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> testing = [{'key1': 1, 'key2': 14, 'key3': 47},{'key1': 222, 'key2': 222, 'key3': 222},{'key1': 0, 'key2': 0, 'key3': 0}]
>>> max(testing,key=lambda x : sum(x.itervalues()))
{'key3': 222, 'key2': 222, 'key1': 222}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also achieve it via using [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) with nested *dict comprehension* expression as:

```
#         assuming the keys in all the sub-lists are same  v
>>> {key: max(d[key] for d in testing) for key in testing[0].keys()}
{'key3': 222, 'key2': 222, 'key1': 222}
```

Comment: As far as I know, that does not answer the question. I think the OP is not looking for the maximum *for each key*, he/she is looking for the *element* in the given list with the largest *sum of elements*. Although it is a bit unclear.